# Javascript wont fire in Html.DropdownList helper in MVC2

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2, select

Can anyone tell me why the javascript won't submit when the button is clicked on the below scenario?

The controller is like so:

```
public ActionResult TestJavaScrip()
 {
         TestEntities db = new Models.TestEntities();

         ViewData["SortOptions"] = new SelectList(db.aspnet_Role, "RoleId", "RoleName");

 return View();
 }
```

The View contains:

```
<form>
<%= Html.DropDownList("mySelect",(SelectList)ViewData["SortOptions"],"Please Choose a Role...") %> 
<input type="button" onclick="getIndex()" value="Alert index of selected option"/>
</form>
```

Javascript in the Site.master head section is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getIndex() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    alert(x.selectedIndex);
}
</script>
```

Rendering as follows:

```
<form>
<select id="mySelect" name="mySelect"><option value="">mySelect</option>
<option value="133d8e56-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-35ee34e845aa">Administrator</option>
<option value="7c2a6ed5-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-fecb42bdeebe">Clerk</option>
<option value="54ebe31d-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-9821df62f5ed">Client</option>
<option value="63e605eb-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-b007189a41e5">CPA</option>
<option value="fb644c83-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-5da4b2dc64a0">Executive</option>
<option value="65efa138-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-098d9195a99d">Master Administrator</option>
<option value="0c863774-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-6c8d2418ca6b">Part Qualified Accountant</option>
</select>


<input type="button" onclick="getIndex()" value="Alert index of selected option"/>
</form>
```

Why is it not firing? I hope someone can see a glaring oversight on my part.

Comment: Output works fine [here](http://jsbin.com/uxulo4#noedit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your using MVC 2 I assume you have access to the JQuery library that comes with it.

Here is some JQuery that will solve your problem, and a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3V3Y9/) so you can see it in action!

You'll find jsfiddle is a life saver for these sorts of things, if you want a straight javascript solution you can pad one out in there too.

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Alert index of selected option"/>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function getIndex() { 
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect"); 
    alert(x.selectedIndex); 
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the great steer on the jquery and jsfiddle, I am using these now.

Comment: The answer in the end was that I had a ready made custom javascript file in the head section which had an over ride to the "alert" function. I had to go through the logical deduction process to discover this.